# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isBatchingLegacy')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to test a react typescript project using jest but it's giving a confusing error:

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.1.0"
}
```

I wrote this basic test which gives the error:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import AddShipmentButton from './AddShipmentButton'

it('works', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<AddShipmentButton />).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

I had to install the dependencies using --legacy-peer-deps. What could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem was that I installed the latest version of react-test-renderer v18.0.1 when the React version is v17.0.2. Installing react-test-renderer version 17.0.2 solved this issue.

Comment: I installed both react and react-test-renderer version 16.x.x, but it throws this issue as well.

Comment: right, installing same version as React fixed the issue

Comment: Which package depend the react-test-renderer? I can only find the react-test-renderer@18.0.2 but I dont know who is using it.

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade your app dependencies like this

```
"react": "~18.0.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.0.0", 
 "react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0"
```

import is wrong as defined on React docs, try with this way

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import AddShipmentButton from './AddShipmentButton'

it('works', () => {
  const tree = TestRenderer.create(<AddShipmentButton />).toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Read usage of TestRenderer [here](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html)

Comment: Changing `renderer` to `TestRenderer` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I see you are downgrade your dependencies you can also upgrade and use like this ,"react": "~18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0" , anyway on react docs used TestRenderer instead of renderer.   https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html

Comment: `import something from '...'` imports the default export from that module. You can give it any name you want, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok I have a check you are right , write what you want )) , for me good aproach use documentation style, you can directly use import { create } from "react-test-renderer" and use it instead , in your code no other usage of TestRenderer , upgrade will be fixed your problem also. Thank you for information @wvdz

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the same version of `react` and `react-test-renderer`

You can change the version of node package using `npm install [package-name]@[version-number]`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your react and react-dom version to a more stable version (17.0.0).

Initially I had the following dependencies and was getting the same error

```js
"react": "^18.0.2",
"react-dom": "^18.0.2"
```

But once I downgraded my dependencies to

```js
"react": "^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.0"
```

The error was resolved